# ActiveRecord: doing a join with unscoped doesn't skip the default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am having some issues when trying to skip a `default_scope` when doing an ActiveRecord `join`.

Even though the codebase is quite large, I am just showing the basics as I think it shows pretty well what the problem is:

```rb
class Client
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company
  default_scope { where(version_id: nil) }
end
```

I am building a complex report, so I need to join multiple tables and filter on them. However, I can't successfully skip the default scope when fetching `Client`s.

```rb
Client.joins(:company).to_sql
# SELECT clients.* FROM clients INNER JOIN companies
# ON companies.id = clients.company_id AND companies.version_id IS NULL
```

As you can see that is automatically including the `Company` `default_scope`. So I tried this:

```rb
Company.unscoped { Client.joins(:company) }.to_sql
# SELECT clients.* FROM clients INNER JOIN companies
# ON companies.id = clients.company_id AND companies.version_id IS NULL
```

Again, I got the same result, even when using `unscoped` with the block.

Then I decided to add a new association to the model, with the `unscoped` scope:

```rb
class Client
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :unscoped_company, -> { unscoped }, foreign_key: :company_id, class_name: "Company"
end
```

Having added that, I gave another try:

```rb
Client.joins(:unscoped_company).to_sql
# SELECT clients.* FROM clients INNER JOIN companies
# ON companies.id = clients.company_id AND companies.version_id IS NULL
```

And still the scoped is being applied.

Do you know how can I successfully join both tables without applying that `default_scope`?
Removing that `default_scope` is not an option as It is a big application and changing that will require too much time.

---

Rails v4.2.7

Ruby v2.2.3

Comment: Do you really need `default_scope`? If removing it you get the expected result, consider to use `scope, :unversioned -> { where(version_id: nil) }` instead.

Comment: Yes, I would like to remove it but that's not an option right now, it would take so much time to refactor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did some research without finding any straight solution.

Here a couple of workarounds. I cannot say if they're going to work in your chained joins.

---

First basic, do it manually:

```
Client.joins("INNER JOINS companies ON companies.id = clients.company_id").to_sql
```

---

Other option define a `CompanyUnscoped` class which inherits from `Company`, removing the default_scope:

```
class CompanyUnscoped < Company

  self.default_scopes = []

end
```

Don't forget to add this line to Client class:

```
belongs_to :company_unscoped, foreign_key: :company_id
```

Then you should be able to call

```
Client.joins(:company_unscoped)
#=> SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" INNER JOIN "companies" ON "companies"."id" = "clients"."company_id"
```

Comment: Thanks @iGian. Even though I don't fully like the workaround, it works great, so I'm marking it as the right answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Apply directly as a class method

```
Client.unscoped.joins(:company).to_sql
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work... It's still adding the company's scope to the join.

Answer (score 0):

You might try https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-unscope but I would've expected https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-unscoped to work. You might try it again without a block, letting it come after the undesired scope is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there isn't any straightforward solution that you are looking for. There are couple of discussion threads for reference.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20679

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20011

But I liked the way what @iGian has suggested.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it manually:

```
Client.joins('inner join company on companies.id = clients.company_id')
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, but even though for the example is ok, in my case, I have many joins to do, and I would like to relay on ActiveRecord for that, otherwise I will need to do them all manually.